# Invertible elements in a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am stuck trying to prove the following: let $\mathbf R$ be a nontrivial commutative ring, $\mathcal M$ be the class of proper maximal ideals of $\mathbf R$ and $J=\bigcap \mathcal M$. Prove that $1+a$ is invertible for all $a\in J$.

My attempt so far: every $M\in\mathcal M$ is maximal, so that $R|M$ is a field. Thus for all $a\in J$ and all $M\in\mathcal M$  there is $b_M$ such that $[1+a]_M [b_M]_M=[1]_M$. From this I deduce that $b_M+ab_M-1\in M$ for all $M$, that $b_M(1+a)\notin M$, that $b_M\notin M$, and so that $[b_M]_M\cap M=\emptyset$ for all $M$, but I really don't know how to use these informations or how to try for a different proof

Comment: I suppose it's not wrong to talk about "the class" of maximal ideals, but there's no reason not to say "the set of maximal ideals."

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem** $\ $ TFAE in ring $\rm\:R\:$ with units $\rm\:U,\:$ ideal $\rm\:J,\:$ and Jacobson radical $\rm\:Jac(R)\:.$

$\rm(1)\quad  J \subseteq Jac(R),\quad $ i.e.  $\rm\:J\:$  lies in every max ideal $\rm\:M\:$ of $\rm\:R\:.$

$\rm(2)\quad  1+J \subseteq U,\quad\ \ $  i.e. $\rm\: 1 + j\:$  is a unit for every $\rm\: j \in J\:.$

$\rm(3)\quad  I\neq 1\ \Rightarrow\  I+J \neq 1,\qquad\ $  i.e.  proper  ideals survive in $\rm\:R/J\:.$

$\rm(4)\quad M\:$ max $\rm\:\Rightarrow  M+J \ne 1,\quad $  i.e. max ideals survive in $\rm\:R/J\:.$

**Proof** $\: $ (sketch) $\ $  With  $\rm\:i \in I,\ j \in J,\:$ and max ideal $\rm\:M,$

$\rm(1\Rightarrow 2)\quad  j \in all\ M\ \Rightarrow\ 1+j \in no\ M\ \Rightarrow\ 1+j\:$ unit.

$\rm(2\Rightarrow 3)\quad i+j = 1\ \Rightarrow\ 1-j = i\:$ unit $\rm\:\Rightarrow  I = 1\:.$

$\rm(3\Rightarrow 4)\ \ \ $  Let $\rm\:I = M\:$ max.

$\rm(4\Rightarrow 1)\quad  M+J \ne 1 \Rightarrow\ J \subseteq M\:$  by  $\rm\:M\:$ max.